# MatPlotLib Python - RGB values from color sensor used to change color of line point

Tags: python, matplotlib, linestyle, drawnow

So I'm working with a TCS3200 color sensor and Arduino Mega 2560 to generate specific RGB values.  Then, through the serial cable, I'm sending data to VIDLE for Python, splitting the 3 data points, and storing them in an array (updating the MatPlotLib plot every 50 data points (per RGB).)

Originally I was plotting the R, G, B values on three separate lines...now I'm plotting a different line, based on a (255,255,255) coordinate system (y-limit is 255*sqrt(3)).

What I want to do is this:  if my RGB values are (220, 60, 140), I want to be able to change the color of the data point based on those values.

The graph point would be sqrt(pow(220,2.0)+pow(60,2.0)+pow(140,2.0)), but the color needs to reflect the RGB value.

How do I do this?

Here's my current plot setup:

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

distance = []
s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/cu.usbmodem1421', baudrate=115200)
plt.ion()
cnt = 0
limit = 255*sqrt(3);
r = 0
g = 0
b = 0

def makeFig():
        plt.ylim(0,limit)
        plt.title('My Live Streaming Sensor Data')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.ylabel('RGB Values')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        # somewhere in the line below I think the RGB dynamics should be reflected
        plt.plot(distance, '-', label='Distance')
        plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=True)
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')

while True:
        while (s.inWaiting()):
               myDataString = s.readline()
               try:
                       dataArray = myDataString.split(',')
                       print (dataArray)
                       r = float(dataArray[0])
                       g = float(dataArray[1])
                       b = float(dataArray[2])
                       d = float(dataArray[3].strip('\r\n')
                       distance.append(d)
                       # before this 'drawnow' gets called, should the RGB values be incorporated into the plot?
                       drawnow(makeFig)
                       plt.pause(0.000001)
                       cnt = cnt + 1
                       if (cnt > 50):
                               distance.pop(0)
               except ValueError:
                       print (myDataString)
```

Comment: See this article on create reproducible examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

As long as this example relies on this mysterious `drawnow` package, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: (same goes for the reliance on a serial port for data. mock that up with a `StringIO` instance of a CSV file)

Comment: `drawnow` is the most useless package I've ever seen. It literaly consists of `plt.clf()`, followed by the function call, and `plt.draw()`. But I agree that a [mcve] should be provided when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to plot some dots at the positions corresponding to the distance from the origin in the RGB cube. Their color will be set to the rgb value tuple.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Mockup Serial
class Serial():
    n = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.maxN = kwargs.get("maxN", 1000)
        self.cols = np.arange(0,240,1)
    def inWaiting(self):
        self.n+=1
        return (self.n<self.maxN)
    def readline(self):
        a = np.random.choice(self.cols,size=3)
        a = list(map(str, a))
        b = str(np.random.randint(0,10))
        return ",".join(a)+","+b+'\r\n'

distance = []
colors = []
s = Serial(port='/dev/cu.usbmodem1421', baudrate=115200)
plt.ion()
cnt = 0
limit = 255.*np.sqrt(3)
r = 0
g = 0
b = 0


plt.ylim(0,limit)
plt.title('My Live Streaming Sensor Data')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylabel('RGB Values')
plt.xlabel('Time')

line,   = plt.plot([],[], '-', color="gray",label='Distance')
scatter  = plt.scatter([],[], s=40, marker='o', label='Hit', zorder=3)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')


while (s.inWaiting()):
    myDataString = s.readline()
    dataArray = myDataString.split(',')
    r = int(dataArray[0])
    g = int(dataArray[1])
    b = int(dataArray[2])
    d = int(dataArray[3].strip('\r\n'))
    distance.append(np.sqrt(r**2+b**2+g**2))
    color = (r/255.,g/255.,b/255.)
    colors.append(color)
    x = range(len(distance))
    line.set_data(x, distance)
    scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x,distance])
    scatter.set_color(colors)
    plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))
    plt.pause(0.01)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    if (cnt > 50):
        distance.pop(0)
        colors.pop(0)
    plt.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: I can produce that graph above, it looks really good.  However, let's say the y-axis is 255*sqrt(3) (which is the maximum distance/diagonal length of an RGB (255,255,255) cube), would I be able to make those red dots different colors based on the RGB value each time one is plotted?

Comment: Would you like to have all dots change their color once a new dot is plotted?

Comment: Not really. So let's say the first dot plotted is based on RGB (120,60,100)...it's y-axis value is ~167, then the next dot is (120,80,110)...y-axis ~181.....the line created by the dots is a positive slope but the dots themselves are the color represented by their RGB value.  If this is stupid, then I might consider putting a decently-sized circle at the top right of the graph, that acts as the color display.

Comment: So each measurement would actually produce a dot, not only some of them? And the dot's color depends on the measurement itself? There are no stupid things; one just has to precise about the requirement.

Comment: Well it could be stupid looking, in the sense that imagine a difficult-to-read-and-observe graph whose main focal line can be any color imaginable...might get weird to look at.  But for now that's what I'm pursuing.   Technically, I have a button that triggers when to capture data...but I took that out just to make sure the graphing works beforehand.  So yes, for now it's plotting dots every 300 ms.  The dot's color depends on the measurement, yes.

Comment: I'm making a fluid detection device...so on this graph will be a target horizontal line that represents the calibrated RGB values of blood (converted to the 255 root 3 axis), so whatever RGB values my device detects after will either hover around that horizontal line, or above/below it so the user can see what they're dealing with.  Along with a color detector to confirm the readings.  Essentially, as far as I know, certain colors will never be truly represented by the graph because the user will never need to detect them.

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope this time my interpretation of what you need is better. Although now I don't know what `distance` should be anymore, because as I understand the quantity to plot is the value calculated from the rgb values as *sqrt(r^2+g^2+c^2)*, which will be calculated in the script and not read in from the device.

Comment: That's awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for!  My next step is to figure out how to get the TCS3200 RGB frequency readings to be in 0-255 range, otherwise the `scatter.set_color(colors)` call will be out of the `[0,1]` range.  Thanks for all your help